# Sonata bundle editable date field

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Sonat admin bundle allow to edit only text fields and boolean, i would like to know if there a way to override sonata make it edit datetime/date fields.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you mean you want datetime/date fields rendered as text field ?

Comment: no, i want to be able to edit the datetime fields

Comment: // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('certifExpiry', 'date', array(
                    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                    'editable' => true
                ))

            ->add('notes', null, array('editable' => true))
the Editable parameter works only for scalar type. how can we make sonata make datetime fields editable too.

Answer (score 0):

At this time , they only support scalar types :

> Theses types accept an editable parameter to edit the value from within the list action. This is currently limited to scalar types (text, integer, url...).

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/field_types.html

I guess to have to digg more into the documentation to get it working. ( See how scalar types are dealt with and try to write similar logic )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in which version they added this (can't find it in the change log), but in admin bundle 3.8.0 adding `'editable' => true'` to a date field in a list makes it editable alright. The value becomes underlined with a dashed line and clicking it opens a jQuery date selector.

Comment: It's work for a `date` format. Unfortunately, it's doesn't work for a `datetime` format.